# Way to get IShellExtInit to work out-of-process

Tags: winapi, com, idl, midl

I'd like to pass an `IShellItemArray` to an out-of-process COM object residing within an exe.  I'd prefer to use existing interfaces before creating my own, so I thought I'd try having the out-of-process object implement `IShellExtInit`.  Seemed like a good fit.

Anyway, it appears that attempting to create/query interface for `IShellExtInit` fails for out-of-process COM servers. I found some [additional evidence](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/3461b1e4c67ce2b4.htm) indicating that it's not possible because that particular interface lacks marshaling support.

Is there anything that can be done to fix that, short of defining my own similar interface (with the `oleautomation` attribute)?  Alternatively, are there any other existing generic interfaces, that work out of process, for passing an `IShellItemArray`?  Thanks for any info.

Comment: A PIDL is just a chunk of data, easy enough to pass to another process.

Answer (score 0):

`IExecuteCommand` is [supported out-of-proc](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119020633/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623/#https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100528-01/?p=13883) where `IObjectWithSelection` is the way the array is passed. Might only work on Win7 and later.

`IDropTarget` is also [supported out-of-proc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183) but it is more work (fake dropping a data object). It works back to at least WinXP if you care about that.

Comment: Do you know how to go about fake dropping a data object?  Thanks.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080724-00/?p=21483